# Which is correct - was or were?

Tags: verb-agreement, disjunction

Consider the following sentence:

> However, if we were great friends with someone who committed murder or robbed a store, we wouldn’t question whether murder or stealing were bad.

Is this correct as written, or should it be "was bad"?

I feel that it should be "was", since the author used "or". If the author had used "and", then "were" seems like it would be more correct. But I am not sure—which is correct, and what is the general rule to follow in these cases?

Comment: @Lambie the question is not about mood but number. In this example, some sort of irrealis mood is called for, which is invariable with respect to number. But in an equivalent indicative sentence, it would matter. Question could be improved.

Comment: This shouldn't have been cross posted (see [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/311344/41273)).

Comment: @Lambie the general question is about disjunction ("what is the general rule to follow in these cases?"). Your response only answers the specific question and is not interesting because the subjunctive does not distinguish number in English.

Comment: @Lambie do you enjoy being this annoyingly pedantic?

Comment: @Lambie Reveal myself as what? Annoyed by someone being annoying? I don't understand why people do this. They goad other people into having a reaction and then act surprised or bemused when people do, in fact, have a reaction. Knock it off.

Comment: @Lambie In any case, the core of the question is not really about mood. It is involved, but not front-and-center. That's clear from the rest of the verbiage in the answer. I don't know why you are intentionally avoiding this. As you can see by the OP's positive response to one of the answers, they simply aren't interested in the mood question, yet you keep wasting time on it.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't contradict myself?

Comment: I misread this question yesterday so I have removed my comments.

Answer (score 2):

As per the subject-verb agreement,

> When acting as subjects of a sentence, gerunds and infinitives are always singular and require singular verbs.

Whether...or, in this context the verb agrees with the nearest noun

since nouns, prior to or and nor have no effects.

> In the sentence, we wouldn’t question whether murder or stealing were bad.

Steal+ing = verbal noun [Gerund].

The appropriate would be, 'was'.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that is what sounded right to me. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer the question and with such a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

correct: was

You are right. Murder *or* stealing *was* bad. Murder *and* stealing *were* bad.

...if we were...wouldn't...or stealing **was** bad. The verb agrees with the nearest element. 'Stealing' is singular. So the verb becomes singular.

If we *were*...we *wouldn’t*...(second conditional sentence)

If he *were*/was rich, he would... (he is not rich)

If I were/was a bird, I would...(I am not a bird)

If stealing were/was good...(Stealing is not good)

If murder were/was good...(Murder is not good)

If it were/was bad...(It is not bad)